# How is class function without definition not causing error

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, sfinae

I was learning some C++ idioms when I came across a sample code for SFINAE, I was perplexed with the code.

Note: `is_ptr()` has no definition.

1. I compiled the code myself, no compiler errors regarding lack of function definition, why?
2. `sizeof()` was used on one of the calls, it apparently executed on the returns of the functions, but then again, there was no definition. How was that possible?

   ```
   template <typename T>
   struct is_pointer
   {
      template <typename U>
         static char is_ptr(U*);

      template <typename X, typename Y>
         static char is_ptr(X Y::*);

      template <typename U>
         static char is_ptr(U (*)());

      static double is_ptr(...);

      static T t;
      enum {value = sizeof(is_ptr(t)) == sizeof(char)};
   };
   ```

Comment: Post code **not** as image but as code formatted text!

Comment: Do you have an instatiation of that template class somewhere?

Comment: I'm on my mobile device right now, so I can't paste a code.

The only usage I had was is_pointer<decltype(I)>::value in the main function

Comment: You don't need the definition to know the sizeof - declaration has all the data you will ever need. Until you actually call the function you don't need the definition at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sizeof` is what is called an un-evaluated context. Within it the expression needs to be only well formed, nothing will actually ever be executed. So a function that is only declared can be used inside without needing an actual definition.

This is because the definition is not required to determine the *type information*. In this case, the overload that is chosen by ADL is the type information in question. It's return type is also available from the declaration alone.

Comment: Thanks, that got me scratching my head, I knew template functions are only created when called, so I thought it was called on value.

Comment: @user3414321 - There's that too, but in this case it's orthogonal to what's happening. Had you attempted to actually execute the templated overload, you'd get the error you expect.